# Converting from Promise with .then() to async/await

Tags: javascript, sqlite, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm looking to better understand the idea of async/await to avoid having nested .then() database calls. The following code simplified code will work correctly, but I have some instances where I would like to make multiple database calls in a row.

```
var sql = require("sqlite3").verbose();
var db = new sql.Database('db.sqlite');

async function query(sql) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
            resolve(rows);
        });
    });
}

query('SELECT name FROM players')
    .then(rows => console.log("Players are: ", rows.map(p => p.name).join(", ")));
```

How do I convert this to use async/await in an elegant manor?

Comment: Can you show example of the multiple calls you want to convert as well?

Comment: I removed a ton of unnecessary logic and have been playing with this example to try and understand this better. This came up when I was inserting data first, then trying to select with issues. Just trying to understand this better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a promise chain like:

```
query('SELECT name FROM players')
  .then(rows => console.log("Players are: ", rows.map(p => p.name).join(", ")));
```

Into async/await, you can do:

```
async function example() {
  const rows = await query('SELECT name FROM players');
  console.log("Players are: ", rows.map(p => p.name).join(", "));
}
```

Note: `await` ([currently](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await)) can only be used within an `async` function, not globally.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sql = require("sqlite3").verbose();
var db = new sql.Database('db.sqlite');


const query = async (sql) => {
    let response;
    await db.all(sql, [], (err,rows) => {
      response = rows;
    })
    return response;
}

const getRows = async () => {
   const rows = await query('SELECT name FROM players');
   console.log("Players are: ", rows.map(p => p.name).join(", ")));
}

getRows();
```

or

```js
const query = async (sql) => {
    const [err, rows] = await db.all(sql, [])
    return [err, rows];
}
```

async can't be in the global scope

Comment: This was the direction I was trying to take it, but could never get it to work. This doesn't print anything to the console though.

Comment: my mistake its because response is getting paired with error because thats the first parameter in .then callback which is undefined. check edit